# Analyzing residuals in logistic regression

Tags: logistic, multiple-regression, residuals

Greetings statistics experts,
I am having a try with the kaggle titanic dataset and am wondering what to do with the residuals after fitting models.
In the case of linear regression you can look at a residual plot and see if there is any discernible pattern, but this is not so straightforward with logistic regression.

How can I improve on my model.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There are partial residuals you can calculate for a logistic model, and these can be used to check the transformations of the variables.  But this is a very subjective and indirect method compared to just modeling flexible predictor effects in the first place, i.e., by using restricted cubic splines.  A detailed case study using the Titanic is given in the Handouts entry in http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/rms.