# What is the binomial residual in logits for an all-success trial?

Tags: regression, logistic, binomial-distribution, markov-chain-montecarlo, residuals

In binomial regression, I have a trial where the model predicts 2 logits (88% predicted success rate) and one data point is 10 successes out of 10 trials (100% observed success rate). What is the residual for this particular data point?

My first hunch was to logit-transform this data point (logit(10/10)) and calculate the difference in logit-space. Naturally, this is wrong since the residual is infinite when $successes = trials$. The same would be true for Bernoulli models.

I am using [JAGS](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mcmc-jags/) to write an AR(N) (autoregressive) binomial model as part of a project to infer change points in time series. The autoregressive coefficient predicts the data point $i$ from the $residual_{i-1}$, so this is where the need to compute residuals steps in. I can see the literature on Pearson residuals as well as deviance residuals, but I am unsure how to relate them to the logit scale. There is a section that looks relevant [here](http://www.flutterbys.com.au/stats/tut/tut10.5b.html), but it is quite involved with matrix multiplication.

Comment: Some possible dups: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/135315/analyzing-residuals-in-logistic-regression, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45050/diagnostics-for-logistic-regression, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31166/logistic-regression-residual-analysis, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29271/interpreting-residual-diagnostic-plots-for-glm-models

Comment: Thanks, @kjetilbhalvorsen. They are all about *assessing* residuals in frequentist settings where the likelihood is conditioned on a summary statistic of many data points. My question is about *modeling* "infinite" single data points (in a Bayesian setting).